# extract medicine name and dose with regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

I would like to extract medical information in text that has the following format
`STRING (CHAR - STRING - STRING - [STRING - STRING - STRING])` for example:

```
OLANZAPINE 10 MG - ORODISPERSIBLE TABLET  (S - n/a - Drug withdrawn - [n/a - n/a - n/a])
```

I would like to extract

- OLANZAPINE 10 MG - ORODISPERSIBLE TABLET
- S
- n/a
- Drug withdrawn
- n/a
- n/a
- n/a

Currently, I use this but it extracts all words seperately

```
s = 'OLANZAPINE 10 MG - ORODISPERSIBLE TABLET  (S - n/a - Drug withdrawn - [n/a - n/a - n/a])'
re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z.0-9/]+", s)

['OLANZAPINE',
 '10',
 'MG',
 'ORODISPERSIBLE',
 'TABLET',
 'S',
 'n/a',
 'Drug',
 'withdrawn',
 'n/a',
 'n/a',
 'n/a']
```

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: @NigelRen I am using Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try catching your needed information by exploiting the dash character `-` and parentheses `(` and `)`.

Here's my attempt:

```
(^|\n)(.*) \(([^\-]+)- ([^\-]+)- ([^-]+)- \[([^\-]+)- ([^\-]+)- ([^\-]+)\]\)
```

You can retrieve your matches using groups from Group 2 to Group 8.

Is it what you're looking for?

Comment: thank you for your reply. Yes they all have same pattern. However, it can fail when the drug name is long and has special characters. For example, how can we extend your solution to work with this: `[[A/HONG KONG/4801/2014 (H3N2)-LIKE STRAIN (A/HONG KONG/4801/2014, X-263B), INFLUENZA VACCINE] (S - Immunisation - n/a - [n/a - n/a - Unknown])`"

Comment: I've updated my answer with your new line for pattern matching @yanisk.

Comment: can you direct me to ways/tools to build such patterns? I'd like to learn

Comment: Glad to have helped! I've started learning time ago on regexone.com, really loved that tutorial. Then doing these regex will come with experience, just keep practicing @yanisk.

Answer (score 2):

If the entries always have the same format it could be something along the lines of:

```
^(?P<capture_1>[\w\s\-]+)\((?P<capture_2>\w)[\s\-]+(?P<capture_3>[\S\w]+)[\s\-]+(?P<capture_4>[\s\w]+)[\s\-]+\[(?P<capture_5>[\S\w]+)[\s\-]+(?P<capture_6>[\S\w]+)[\s\-]+(?P<capture_7>[\S\w]+)\]\)
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/zCCWh2/1

Comment: was this what you had in mind?

Answer (score 2):

The pattern that you used `[a-zA-Z.0-9/]+` is a character class that matches 1 or more times any of the listed characters.

It does not take any context into account like matching parenthesis or differentiating between a single or multiple characters.

You might use a pattern like:

```
(.+?)\s+\(([A-Za-z])\s+-\s+([^-]+)\s+-\s+([^-]+?)\s+-\s+\[([^][\s]+)\s+-\s+([^][\s]+)\s+-\s+([^][\s]+)]\)
```

The separate parts match:

- `(.+?)` Capture 1+ characters as least as possible
- `\s+\(` Match 1+ whitespace chars and `(`
- `([A-Za-z])` Capture a single char
- `\s+-\s+` Match `-` between 1+ whitspace chars
- `([^-]+)` Capture 1+ chars other than `-`
- `\s+-\s+` Match `-` between 1+ whitspace chars
- `([^-]+?)` Capture 1+ chars other than `-` as least as possible
- `\s+-\s+` Match `-` between 1+ whitspace chars
- `\[` Match `[`
- `([^][\s]+)` Capture 1+ chars other than a whitespace char or square brackets
- `\s+-\s+` Match `-` between 1+ whitspace chars
- `([^][\s]+)` Capture 1+ chars other than a whitespace char or square brackets
- `\s+-\s+` Match `-` between 1+ whitspace chars
- `([^][\s]+)` Capture 1+ chars other than a whitespace char or square brackets
- `]\)` Match `])`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HVu8ol/1).

Note that `\s` can also match a newline.

Comment: thanks, Can you make it to work on long first drug name. such as: `[A/HONG KONG/4801/2014 (H3N2)-LIKE STRAIN (A/HONG KONG/4801/2014, X-263B), B/BRISBANE/60/2008-LIKE STRAIN (B/BRISBANE/60/2008, WILD TYPE), A/CALIFORNIA/7/2009 (H1N1)PDM09-DERIVED STRAIN USED (NYMC X-181), A/HONG KONG/4801/2014 (H3N2)-LIKE STRAIN (A/HONG KONG/4801/2014, X-263B), B/BRISBANE/60/2008-LIKE STRAIN (B/BRISBANE/60/2008, WILD TYPE), A/MICHIGAN/45/2015 (H1N1)PDM09-LIKE STRAIN (A/SINGAPORE/GP1908/2015, IVR-180), INFLUENZA VACCINE] (S - Influenza immunisation - Not applicable - [n/a - 1{DF} - n/a])"`

Comment: Edit: Answer from @lemon seems to work for that example

Comment: @yanisk Ow yes sure, you can make a small change like https://regex101.com/r/HVu8ol/1 but you can make it as specific as you want of course